# Move Div left/right and Up/Down by clicking on another div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Based on the below answers, I have managed to slid div left/right but facing some problem regards to top div. Now I want is 
1.Make both brown lines thinner (If I change the width, it spoils animations)
2.slide div left/right when clicking on vertical brown line and re-size top div's width accordingly.
3. Slide top div Up/down when clicking on horizontal brown line. I could do it partially but not perfectly. Can someone please help me. Below i

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script src="JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="JQuery-UI.js"></script>
<%-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>--%>
<link href="App_Themes/Design.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="App_Themes/PageDesigns.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#showHideDiv").click(function () {
            if (!$('#divMenu').hasClass("off")) {
                $('#divMenu').animate({ 'margin-left': '-95%' }, 500);
                $('#divMenu').addClass("off");
                $('.div3').animate({ 'left': '-10%', 'width': '99.3%', 'margin-left': '-10.5%' }, 500);
                //$('.div3').animate({ 'left': '-10%', 'width': '99.3%', 'margin-left': '-10.5%' }, 500);

            }
            else {
                $('#divMenu').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 500);
                $('#divMenu').removeClass("off");
                $('.div3').animate({ 'left': '-0%', 'width': '89%', 'margin-left': '-0%' }, 500);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="float: left; width: 11%; height: 850px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <div id="divMenu" class="">
            Sidebar- Menu
        </div>
        <div id="showHideDiv" style="float: left; height: 850px; width: 5%; background-color: brown;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3" style="float: left; width: 89%; ">
        <div style="float: left; background-color: #93D209; width: 100%; height: 50px;display:block">
            hello
        </div>
        <div style="height: 0.5%; width: 100%; background-color: brown;display:block">
            hi
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A fiddle ([http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)) and some more details about what exaclty doesn't work or you couldn't do would be very helpful

Comment: Typically sliding effects use `animate` on either a `margin-left` property (for relative elements), or the css `left` property (for absolute elements).

Comment: @Spokey.. I am not able to slide the div left/right when click on another div. Also I cannot re-size top div when top div(div3 in figure) slides-in or slides-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wL8K6/2/)**

First I've set .div3 css to this:

```
.div3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 89%;
    margin-left: 11%;
}
```

*Margin-left is set initially depending on the total width of the sidebar. And set it to position absolute so it would not fall down. You could also set it to fixed if that suits you.*

On click of the sidebar switch, the .div3 is set to animate its margin-left to 0% and increase its width to 99% to 100% so it would take the whole screen.

```
 $('.div3').animate({ 'margin-left': '0%', 'width': '99.3%'}, 500);
```

While toggling back the sidebar, animates the .div3 to its original/initial margin-left 11% and width 89%.

```
 $('.div3').animate({ 'margin-left': '11%', 'width': '89%'}, 500);
```

as for the top switch, I've added this jQuery:

```
 $("#switch2").click(function () {
        if (!$('#topDiv').hasClass("off")) {
            $('#topDiv').animate({ 'margin-top': '-95%' }, 500);
            $('#topDiv').addClass("off");

        }
        else {
            $('#topDiv').animate({ 'margin-top': '0px' },500);
            $('#topDiv').removeClass("off");
        }
    });
```

and added the id attributes (#topDiv and #switch2) to the concerned html tags.

LIKE:

```
<div class="div3">
        <div id="topDiv">
            hello
        </div>
        <div id="switch2">
            hi
        </div>
</div>
```

whole jQuery script:

```
$("#showHideDiv").click(function () {
            if (!$('#divMenu').hasClass("off")) {
                $('#divMenu').animate({ 'margin-left': '-95%' }, 500);
                $('#divMenu').addClass("off");
                $('.div3').animate({ 'margin-left': '0%', 'width': '99.3%'}, 500);

            }
            else {
                $('#divMenu').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 500);
                $('#divMenu').removeClass("off");
                $('.div3').animate({ 'margin-left': '11%', 'width': '89%'}, 500);
            }
        });
     $("#switch2").click(function () {
            if (!$('#topDiv').hasClass("off")) {
                $('#topDiv').animate({ 'margin-top': '-95%' }, 500);
                $('#topDiv').addClass("off");

            }
            else {
                $('#topDiv').animate({ 'margin-top': '0px' },500);
                $('#topDiv').removeClass("off");
            }
        });
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/wL8K6/2/)**

Comment: @Froient..
$('.div3').animate({'left':'-11%','width' : '100%' ,'margin-left' : '11%' },100);
This is not working properly.
If I add $('.div3').animate({'margin-left' : '-10.5%' },500);, then it does not re-size the div3

Comment: @Froient.. I have edited (Extended requirement) the question. Cam you please help me again?

Comment: @Froient.. The above code works fine but when the side bar slides to left, top bar falls down for a moment. This effect is clearly visible in firefox. I tried various thing but cannot do it. It would be your great help if you can explain above code as I am new to Jquery.

Comment: @Chirag Fanse I see, please check the updated answer and I've also updated the demo in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Froient.. It now stopped working as it should work. On sliding the sidebar, top bar falls down and it remains the down. As I tried, if I remove 'width':'99.3%' from line $('.div3').animate({ 'left': '-10%', 'width': '99.3%', 'margin-left': '-10.5%' }, 500), it keeps the position of top bar but does not resize it. I think width is causing some problem.

Comment: remove also the left: on the animate line. and make sure the div3 is in position:absolute.
It seems working here http://jsfiddle.net/wL8K6/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="container">
```

```
<div class="menu-btn">
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <h6>click me</h6> 
</a>
```

```
.container { width:150px; height:500px; background:#000; margin-left:-150px;
```

}

```
.menu-btn { width:50px; height:20px; background:#d2d2d2; position: fixed;
```

z-index: 999;top: 20px;left: 0;margin-left: 25px;}

```
var flagswap=0;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.menu-btn a').click(function()
{
    if(flagswap==0)
    {
        $('.container').animate({marginLeft:0},500);
        $('.menu-btn').animate({marginLeft:'170px'},500);
        flagswap=1;
    }
    else
    {
        $('.menu-btn').animate({marginLeft:'25px'},500);
        $('.container').animate({marginLeft:'-150px'},500);
        flagswap=0;
    }
});  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uBhR6/